# Web service for iphone app that get post method

Tags: c#, iphone, .net

i want to build a web service for iphone app that get the msg from the iphone in a post method and not in the URL, until now i build web service that i call them in somethong like this:

```
http://mydomain.co.il/example/default.aspx?name=123&age=54
```

but i want to know how i build in visual studio web service that get all of this info in a post method that send from the iphone in XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article will give you a good understanding of how to communicate with XML web services from within your iPhone application, and the examples will provide a solid foundation for consuming other web services in your own projects.

[Link: Consuming XML Web Services in iPhone Applications](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43209/1954)